# AppEngine Python APIs Exception Handling

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the app I'm currently working on (2.7 runtime), I'm trying to make sure that exceptions at the API level (i.e. not my code) are handled correctly within my application. However, it appears that Google/AppEngine handle those exceptions internally and doesn't bubble them up. For instance, using `Thing` which is a previously defined `ndb.Model`

```
t = Thing(id=1,name='thingy')
try:
   t.put()
except Exception as e:
   self.log(e)
   self.abort(500)
```

In the unlikely event that something goes awry with the `put()` I have no way to catch/log that event -- or is there?

A similar thing happens with storing data to the blobstore where exceptions are, apparently, caught and raised internally and leaving no chance for me to log those.

Perhaps I'm missing a key point? I've looked through the API docs but the exceptions raised by services and how to catch them doesn't seem to be a priority for documentation team.

Answer (score 1):

Actually App Engine logs every single request. Just go to the application's dashboard and click on **Logs**.

If you want to log something on your own you should use the logging library and you can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging).

So instead of `self.log` you should use `logging.error`.

Comment: self.log is a method I have created that uses the logging module.

Comment: @Syrahn can you also include the `Thing class` and the code for the `self.log` in your question to investigate more?